# By joining both tables, the results of the sums are duplicated

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates, mysql-workbench

I have two tables, one shows me the units that I bought from the product and the units received from the product, in the second table the price of the product per store, each store has a different price for the product. I need to deliver the total value purchased and the total value received and the difference between what was purchased and what was received.

So having each store its own price, makes the summary add up all the values ​​and the result is extremely big.

CURRENT QUERY:

```
Select NROOC,sum(cant_oc), sum(CANT_REC), 
        sum(cant_oc)-sum(CANT_REC) as DIF,
        (sum(cant_oc*costo_PPF))-(sum(CANT_REC*costo_PPF)) as DIF_costo
from oc_contenedores_odbms 
    left join costo_PPF on oc_contenedores_odbms.SKU=costo_PPF.sku
where NROOC in ('9053963');
```

Name Table 1:costo_PPF

```
 +-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+--+
 | #           |  sku     |  costo_PPF |  fecha_actualizacion |  |
 |   id_tienda |          |            |                      |  |
 +-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+--+
 | 2           | 2618796  | 6710,38    |  2019-06-05          |  |
 +-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+--+
 | 2           | 2669161  | 6076,25    |  2019-06-05          |  |
 +-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+--+
 | 2           |  266917X | 6292,23    |  2019-06-05          |  |
 +-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+--+
 | 2           | 2669188  | 6289,89    |  2019-06-05          |  |
 +-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+--+
 | 2           |  266920X | 5693,62    |  2019-06-05          |  |
 +-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+--+
 | 2           | 2742322  | 6399,75    |  2019-06-05          |  |
 +-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+--+
 | 3           | 2669161  | 6066,39    |  2019-06-05          |  |
 +-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+--+
 | 3           |  266917X | 5981,14    |  2019-06-05          |  |
 +-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+--+
 | 3           | 2669188  | 6496,81    |  2019-06-05          |  |
 +-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+--+
 | 3           |  266920X | 5723,14    |  2019-06-05          |  |
 +-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+--+
 | 3           | 2742322  | 6364,17    |  2019-06-05          |  |
 +-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+--+
 | 3           | 2618796  | 6710,38    |  2019-06-05          |  |
 +-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+--+
```

Name Table 2:oc_contenedores_odbms

```
 +----------+---------+----------+-----------+--------+------+
 |  SKU     |  NROOC  |  CANT_OC |  CANT_REC |  LOCAL |  DIF |
 +----------+---------+----------+-----------+--------+------+
 | 2618796  | 9053963 | 744      | 744       | 508    | 0    |
 +----------+---------+----------+-----------+--------+------+
 | 2669161  | 9053963 | 2232     | 0         | 508    | 2232 |
 +----------+---------+----------+-----------+--------+------+
 |  266917X | 9053963 | 3720     | 744       | 508    | 2976 |
 +----------+---------+----------+-----------+--------+------+
 | 2669188  | 9053963 | 2232     | 1488      | 508    | 744  |
 +----------+---------+----------+-----------+--------+------+
 |  266920X | 9053963 | 1728     | 0         | 508    | 1728 |
 +----------+---------+----------+-----------+--------+------+
 | 2742322  | 9053963 | 968      | 0         | 508    | 968  |
     +----------+---------+----------+-----------+--------+------+
```

Result actual:

```
+---------+---------------+----------------+-------+-------------+
| NROOC   | Suma(CANT_OC) | Suma(CANT_REC) | DIF   | DIF_costo   |
+---------+---------------+----------------+-------+-------------+
| 9053963 | 23248         | 5952           | 17296 |105.224.862,2|
+---------+---------------+----------------+-------+-------------+
```

Expected result:

```
+---------+---------------+----------------+------+---------------+
| NROOC   | Suma(CANT_OC) | Suma(CANT_REC) | DIF  | DIF_costo     |
+---------+---------------+----------------+------+---------------+
| 9053963 | 11624         | 2976           | 8648 | 52.126.284,72 |
+---------+---------------+----------------+------+---------------+
```

Comment: It would help if you used meaningful English table and column names for your examples. Trying to dig through it anyways it seems that your purchase table does not have an ID for the store where the items were purchased from. Without a way to identify the store you won't be able to get the exact cost. Best you can probably do is `avg` / `max` / `min` aggregation on the costs.